# Вылетает приложение при создание фрагмента java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragment-manager

У меня есть главная Activity с контейнером для фрагментов. В этот контейнер я помещаю фрагмент с еще 2 фрагментами в виде Tab-ов (2 таба). Если войти в приложение (авторизация через Facebook) и сразу же использовать Fragment с Tab-ами, то приложение вылетает на строке **at com.app.pollee.fragments.TopFragment.initTabs(TopFragment.java:107)**
При повторном входе в приложение все работает отлично!

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1470)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:617)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:420)
    at com.app.pollee.fragments.TopFragment.initTabs(TopFragment.java:107)
    at com.app.pollee.fragments.TopFragment.access$000(TopFragment.java:25)
    at com.app.pollee.fragments.TopFragment$1.requestSuccess(TopFragment.java:83)
    at com.app.pollee.managers.ServerRequestManager$7.onResponse(ServerRequestManager.java:168)
    at com.app.pollee.managers.ServerRequestManager$7.onResponse(ServerRequestManager.java:150)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

**Фрагмент который помещается в контейнер активити**

```
    public class TopFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private Context fragmentContext;
    private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

    private static TopFragment fragment;

    //Синглтон
    public static TopFragment getInstance(){
        if (fragment==null) {
            fragment = new TopFragment();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view==null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top, container, false);
        }

        fragmentContext = getActivity();
        fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) getActivity();

         initTabs();

        return view;
    }

    private void initTabs() {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        TabsPagerFragmentAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(),
                fragmentContext);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

**Адаптер табов**

```
public class TabsPagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private String[] tabs;

    public TabsPagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_top_array);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                FirstTopTabsFragment fist = new FirstTopTabsFragment();
                return fist;
            case 1:
                SecondTopTabsFragment second = new SecondTopTabsFragment();
                return second;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: А если вместо `fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` взять `getChildFragmentManager()`? А вообще фрагмент во фрагмент класть - плохая идея. Лучше ViewPager в отдельной активити показывать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а что тогда в конструктор TabsPagerFragmentAdapter написать первым параметром?

Comment: Ну, конструктор, вроде, не надо менять. Просто при вызове его попробуйте поменять значение... Я вообще не уверен, что получится.

Comment: Да, и вот эта проверка совсем по мне так не нужна:  if (view==null)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ругается на несовместимость support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: Угу.. Ну, попробуйте тогда в onActivityCreated или в onResume перенести вызов метода initTabs